# which is better crystal report or creating PDF for final report

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports, itext

I have extracted PDF with font color, font family font weight and font style of a text. I am supposed to make a report which includes details which are extracted values in the report. The size of PDF are very small and some are very big.

So to do a final report is it better to use crystal report or create PDF using iTextSharp?

Comment: IMO, Crystal report, You can later export the report to PDF or other formats from Crystal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use crystal report because u can convert it to other file format like excel, rpt, pdf